# Find specific selectors using jade template in node

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pug

I need a way to find specific selectors defined in a jade template. Let's say it could be any element with special id prefix (`[id^="prefix"]`). Based on that I want to generate variables and feed them to layout and other templates logic.

So far I've identified several ways:

1. A very complex regex. It will be too overcomplicated because of unknown nesting, unknown inner content which I will need to have and etc.
2. Compile to html and use `cheerio` or `jsdom`. Which will work but then I'll need to recompile again based on specific nodes found and information from them.

Am I missing any options? Anything from the jade box which could help?
Regex seems to be the best way but I am afraid it's nearly impossible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally I would say: Go and use selectors on the DOM via jsdom or whatever. The whole thing sounds a bit uncommon... could you briefly explain your use case? Maybe there's another way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: To use jsdom I'll need to compile jade template to html first. What I don't want to do :). I've already explained the case briefly - given a jade template - I want to find elements and their content by a selector (`[id^="prefix"]` for instance) but without compilation to html.

Comment: You can call `jade.Parser.parse` and walk the AST.